# GeoExt form and file upload

Tags: javascript, geoext

I have a GeoExt form and want to do file upload here. But i never work with GeoEXT. I have this.

```
buttons: [{
  text: 'Загрузить',
  handler: function(){
  if(fp.getForm().isValid() && Ext.getCmp('opinions').getValue()=="blabla"){
    form_action=1;
    fp.getForm().submit({
             url: '<portlet: actionURL>',
             waitMsg: 'WAITING...',
     success: function(fp, o) {
              DO SOMETHING
              }
             }
            }
          }]
```

This is correct?
What arguments use in  `success: function(fp, o)`? First argument is `FormPanel` but i dont understand what is second.
Another question how to do asynchronous file upload in this case?